# Server notification of client state

Tags: client-server

Sorry for trivial question but I'm planning to create server application, but first I need to write down all possible (outline)
server scenario; I'm puzzled with one question of how server informs or gets state of client and notify it to other already connected to this server, clients.

PS After authorization we already be aware of client's state but what of further state of client,
How server knows about this, I think it's server's initiative to do that if yes HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's the client that should inform the server when something changes, otherwise you're wasting traffic by constantly polling the clients even when nothing has changed.

But this depends on what it is you're doing. For real-time scenarios, for example with a multiplayer game, the clients could constantly send their state several times per second even if nothing has changed. Likewise, the server would send the current state to all clients regardless of whether there were any changes or not.